# Is it possible to mix 32bit and 64bit components with different languages in a single MSI?

Tags: windows, windows-installer

Is it possible to mix 32bit and 64bit components with different languages in a single MSI?

I need to Mix 32bit English,  32bit German 64bit English,  64bit German components in a single MSI. I am able to create separate 4 MSI's using Visual Studio(Setup and Deployment). Using NSIS, I can really mix 32bit English,  32bit German 64bit English,  64bit German components in a single Setup.exe file and install the correct components at installtime(based on selected language - English or German and System Architecture 32bit or 64 bit). Is it possible to create a single MSI incorporating the above requirements using any of the Windows Installer Tools? (I know, in Visual studio, it is not possible, WIX - I dont know, or Any other tool). Any Help is greaten appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at Inno Setup. As far as I know it can do this just fine.

[Edit: ah, it doesn't produce MSIs though, it produces setup executables.]

[Edit2: There's some info here about making Inno setup executables that run silently and then packaging them within an MSI: http://www.appdeploy.com/messageboards/tm.asp?m=10846&mpage=1&key=&#10846 ]

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a limitation of the WiX toolset, it's a limitation of the Windows Installer (MSI) itself.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible, because of Windows Installer limitation:

- 32-bit packages that contain only 32-bit components.
- 64-bit packages containing some 32 bit components.
- 64-bit packages containing only 64 bit components.

Here is more information: [About Windows Installer on 64-Bit Operating Systems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367451%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2008/01/15/different-packages-are-required-for-different-processor-architectures.aspx).